# How to write a self join in JPA for MySQL

Tags: mysql, jpa, join, hql

I have a table called groups with four [relevant] columns; **id, parent_id, activated_date** and **type**. parent_id and activated_date are nullable, and a group is considered to be activated if it has an activated_date prior to today, is of type typeA, or its parent group is activated.

| id | parent_id | activated_date | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 2020-01-01 | typeA |
| 2 | 3 |  | typeB |
| 3 |  | 2020-01-01 | typeC |

I am trying to write a query that will list all of the activated groups, and I'm running into a very confusing issue. (Note: I am using CASE statements because in JPA conditional expressions are not allowed in SELECT clauses, but they are inside of CASE expressions)

If my WHERE clause looks like:

```
(CASE
  WHEN
    g.activated_date is not null AND
    g.activated_date < CURDATE()
    THEN TRUE
  WHEN
    g.group_type = 'typeA'
    THEN TRUE
  ELSE FALSE
END) = TRUE
```

Then I find 9000 activated groups (or 1000 deactivated groups if I change to FALSE). This is expected, there are a total of 10,000 groups.

BUT when I add an additional condition to check the parent's status (Note: this does not need to be recursive, groups cannot have 'grandparents' in this use case):

```
(CASE
  WHEN
    g.activated_date is not null AND
    g.activated_date < CURDATE()
    THEN TRUE
  WHEN
    g.group_type = 'typeA'
    THEN TRUE
  WHEN
    (g.parent.activated_date is not null AND g.parent.activated_date < CURDATE()) OR
    (g.parent.group_type = 'typeA')
    THEN TRUE
  ELSE FALSE
END) = TRUE
```

Then I am suddenly finding I have 8500 activated groups (and 750 deactivated). I cannot account for the missing 750 groups; am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you think you'll need case. How would you write it in SQL?

Comment: From the post: (Note: I am using CASE statements because in JPA conditional expressions are not allowed in SELECT clauses, but they are inside of CASE expressions)

Comment: As for how I would write it in SQL.. I'm not really sure. I struggle with SQL, but in adding this filter I only have access to the WHERE clause anyways..

Comment: Do you have g instances that don't have 'parent' references? A null in this join operation removes them from the results and might account for the missing 750 rows of data. You'll want to use a left join to fetch parents if this is the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your full query isn't clear, but if 'g' instances don't have parents, they are removed from the query results. You would need to use a left join on this relationship to have them included in results.

```
"select <your select clause> where G g left join g.parent parent where <your Where clause>"
```

Where ever you were using g.parent in your select or where clauses you then need to just use `parent`. So

```
(CASE
  WHEN
    g.activated_date is not null AND
    g.activated_date < CURDATE()
    THEN TRUE
  WHEN
    g.group_type = 'typeA'
    THEN TRUE
  WHEN
    parent is not null AND
    ((parent.activated_date is not null AND parent.activated_date < CURDATE()) OR
    (parent.group_type = 'typeA'))
    THEN TRUE
  ELSE FALSE
END) = TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! This explains the missing results perfectly.

Hypothetically, if I only have access to there WHERE clause, is there any other way I can replicate this solution? (The use case is that this is one of many optional filters on this table - there are a large number of columns left out of this question for simplicity's sake - and I don't want to introduce a join in situations where this particular filter isn't being used)

Comment: Not with a JPQL string type query, as JPA dictates that '.' be an inner join except when used to define a left join in the from clause (and a few other situations in the select clause where a null can be used by aggregate functions). criteria query api doesn't allow specifying the join type within a 'get' call, but does allow it on the join api, making it more inline with JPQL, but this is the approach I would go, as would allow reusing the same join if you need it for other filters later on - and your logic should only add it if you are adding this filter anyway.

Comment: I tried this out adding the left join in direct sql and see the results I expect! However, when adding the left join in JPQL I'm still seeing missing results when I add in the new WHEN clause as you wrote above. (I've also tried with just parent.activated_date and parent.group_type instead of "g." for both of those, with the same results) Curiously, while there are the exact same NUMBER of missing results, they are not the same records - specifically, I can see some results with null parent_ids.

Comment: select * from GroupEntity g left join g.parent parent <where clause>

Comment: Check the SQL issued, but I've modified the 'case' statement from my answer as I had left in a few "g.parent" reference in it, which force an inner join still. You'll want to use 'parent' instead to reuse the left join; any use of 'g.parent' in your query defines an inner join that will either be new or force the existing 'parent' to use an inner join (depends on how JPA parses your query).

Comment: I was able to output the generated SQL to logging and it is doing a cross join

Comment: Update: the left join was working after following your suggestion - we were doing a separate query for a count of the results which lacked the joins, and I was seeing the output of that rather than the query I thought I was seeing.